# Why does Eclipse creates warning on HTML script tag?

Tags: html, eclipse, warnings

I have a warning on the line including the javascript file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
```

The warning is "Multiple annotations found at this 
 line:
    - Undefined attribute name (src).
    - Undefined attribute name 
     (type)."

I can't see where the problem is!

Comment: Could it be that eclipse doesn't recognize the doctype, and falls back to something really, really ancient? This is pure speculation, though... Maybe try with a HTML4 doctype just to check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the doc type. Eclipse is going to validate the DOM against the DTD. If unknown entities are not clearly defined in the DTD, then Eclipse will raise warnings.

Comment: So eclipse doesn't understand HTML 5? When are they planning to add that feature?

Comment: @Pekka - Are there any tools around at the moment, other than dedicated validators, that do an adequate job of flagging up invalid HTML5? With no DTD or schema, HTML5 requires implementing or integrating a lot of HTML5-specialised validator code, for a spec that isn't currently stable. I wouldn't expect the feature to be added soon.

Comment: @Alohci true, but I *would* somehow expect tools to fall back to HTML 4 in that case, where src is a valid property. I can be wrong with that expectation though

Comment: @Pekka - I guess fallback is a separate issue, but fair point.

Comment: Ok I dropped the HTML5 idea, I thought it was stable... My bad.

Comment: @Pekka, is it safe to drop the <!doctype .. from an html document?

Comment: i.e. if ur familiar with html, what's the risk of dropping it for the convenience of not seeing this eclipse warning

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of an explicit doctype, you should check if the Property dialog for the file has a page for deciding what doctype to use as a default.  HTML5 was only very recently added: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/wtp-dev/msg07790.html .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<!DOCTYPE html>`, using this
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: So your solution is not to use HTML5 but XHTML? That's like fixing your car by buying a bicycle.