# Undefined attribute name (aria-hidden)

Tags: eclipse, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2). For jsp pages, the JSP validator reports this warning on a bootstrap alert box like the following

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    An error occurred
</div>
```

The closest similar question I've seen is [Why does Eclipse creates warning on HTML script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268976/why-does-eclipse-creates-warning-on-html-script-tag) but I'm assuming the latest version of Eclipse has HTML5 support.

Is the warning valid, or is there a way to get it to go away.

Comment: Change it to 'data-aria-hidden'. It should fix the issue. I use netbeans. Usually this solves the problem for me.

Comment: @Adi That does take away the warning. However, doesn't that also negate the purpose of the aria-hidden attribute? http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden

Comment: You are right. Anyway check in your browser. As I said, I do it for angular attributes and not sure about the attribute you mentioned. That's why I add comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded to Eclipse Luna and this warning isn't shown anymore so I guess the solution now is to upgrade to Luna.